# измените код , чтобы простые множители выводились не в строчку, а в один столбец

Tags: python

```
def func1 (x , d =2):
    while x > 1:
     g , r = divmod (x , d)
     if r:
        d += 1
     else:
        yield d
        x = g
n = int(input(" Уведіть ціле число: "))
print ('{ } = { }' .format (n, ' * ' .join(map(str, func1 (n)))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в вывод `\n`. Это автоматически приводит к созданию новой строки.

Comment: увы , но я пробовала и вставляла \n в последней строке , но выбивало инвалид либо ошибку

Comment: Где именно вставляли?

Comment: в команде print ; можете показать куда нужно вставить \n , чтобы ответ был столбиком?

Comment: Попробуйте так: `...(n, '\n' .join...`

Comment: сработало , спасибо за помощь

Comment: Рад был помочь)